# Unable to browse nodejs web app running docker container

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker.io. I crated image using standard image ubuntu from index.docoker.io successfully in aws instance.I installed node.js and simple web app in the image and created docker container and test successfully with the following:
    curl -i localhost:49160
in the browser I specified hostip:1704 but I am not getting the page

Comment: can you post your Dockerfile and command you run the container?

Comment: FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER s rambabu
RUN apt-get install -y python-software-properties python
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
RUN echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
#RUN apt-get install -y npm
ADD /src /src
RUN cd src; npm install
EXPOSE  1704
CMD ["node", "/src/index.js"]

Comment: The run command I have used is:sudo docker run -p 49160:1704 -d ssit/ssit-node-hello:latest

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the wrong port to access the application. Try pointing your browser  to `http://<host_ip>:49160`

The application inside the container is exposing the port 1704, and when you run the container with the parameter `-p 49160:1704`, you're forwarding the port 49160 on your host machine to the port 1704 inside the container. When using the browser to access the app, you use the IP of the host machine and the open port, in this case 49160.

See the [Redirect ports](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/port_redirection/) documentation for more info.